# Separate words into list, except for symbols

Tags: python, split, tweets

I'm creating a project where I'll receive a list of tweets (Twitter), and then check if there words inside of a `dictionary`, which has words that certain values. I've gotten my code to take the words, but I don't know how to eliminate the symbols like: `, . "`:

Here's the code:

```
def getTweet(tweet, dictionary):
score = 0
seperate = tweet.split(' ')
print seperate
print "------"    
if(len(tweet) > 0):
    for item in seperate:
        if item in dictionary:
            print item
            score = score + int(dictionary[item])
    print "here's the score: " + str(score)
    return score
else:
    print "you haven't tweeted a tweet"
    return 0
```

Here's the parameter/tweet that will be checked:

```
getTweet("you are the best loyal friendly happy cool nice", scoresDict)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of all the non alphanumerical values you can try:

```
import re
re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', string)
```

the flag [^\w] will do the trick for you!

Comment: Why not just use pattern `r'\W'`?

Comment: Might as well do `re.split('\W*', tweet)`, but I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I did what you had said, and then turned the words into a list. However, this is what happened.    `code`  you  are  the  best  loyal  friendly happy cool nice (function has taken out symbols, but when created into the list, it takes back the symbols)
['you,', 'are.', 'the;', 'best]', 'loyal[', 'friendly', 'happy', 'cool', 'nice']
------
friendly
happy
cool
nice
here's the score: 9 (then it only split the words without symbols) Sorry guys, I'm a noob at python.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the split, replace the characters with spaces, and then split on the spaces.

```
import re

line = '  a.,b"c'
line = re.sub('[,."]', ' ', line)

print line  # '  a  b c'
```

Comment: Probably not the best because you have to enumerate what counts as punctuation.  Better is MatteoD's pattern `r'[^\w]'` (not word).

Comment: It depends on the data and intent: do you want to split `it's` or `blue-brown` or `N_t`?